# How can I add folders to DockbarX?

Tags: dockbarx

To keep a long story short, I have settled with DockbarX(Applet 0.91.4), as my main dock like application, now, what I am wondering is, how do I add folders to it?

Applications works fine, but I have folders with files in them, and I want to be able to click the folder on DockbarX, and select which file I want to run from it!

Example of what I an looking for

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this is possible with DockbarX?

Comment: I have seen other Linux dock like applications do this. I have selected  DockbarX, because it's highly tweak-able, and it does what I want it to.  Except this folder thing.

Comment: Have you attempted to do any research on how to do it with other bars? I'd think the steps would be similar

Comment: @DavidCole Cairo-Dock does this automatically, but, configuring it is a terrible job. The entire interface screams noise. Can't find my way in it. Plus, have to disable allot of crap, I don't want, which I have to find first where I can disable them. Dockbarx, was setup in minutes. So choose DBX. Only thing now is the Folder supports. Then I'm done.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `usr/share/applications/` and drag&drop `computer` icon on `dockbarx`. It works on my Linux Mint 17.2 MATE 64.

Comment: This just opens the file manager. This is what I'm looking for: http://www.muylinux.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/Stacks.png